# Android. OKHttp. How do I find the time server from body POST response?

Tags: android, http, time, server, okhttp

To send a POST request with the Android library is used OKHTTP. How do I find the time server?

```
String post(String...url) throws IOException {
        FormEncodingBuilder form = new FormEncodingBuilder();
        RequestBody formBody =form.build();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .header("Cookie", x)
                .url(url[0])
                .post(formBody)
                .build();
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        return response.body().string();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Time server and server time are different things and you probably want to know how to get server time.

First of all, you need a server that somehow provides time, so possible solutions are to find a webserver or create your own. Use its url to connect to it.

The server can offer time in its response in different ways:
- as a header which has "Date" name
- as a body which you have to know how to parse.